# Loading GML data into Postgres with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, gml, ordnance-survey

I'm working with a new OS dataset, Highways Network, trying to get it loaded into Postgres and set up in some kind of usable state.

I've loaded all the data already, but it seems some elements of what is contained in the GML files have not been included.

Here is a section of the GML:

```
<ram:Maintenance gml:id="id_1770MA01526959">
  <gml:identifier codeSpace="http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ids">http://data.os.uk/id/1770MA01526959</gml:identifier>
  <net:networkRef>
    <net:NetworkReference>
      <net:element xlink:href="#usrn44302253"/>
    </net:NetworkReference>
  </net:networkRef>
  <net:inspireId>
```

The element that has not loaded is: xlink:href="#usrn44302253"

If I run ogrinfo on the GML, it does not even pick up the #usrn:

```
OGRFeature(Maintenance):131433
gml_id (String) = id_1050MA01364874
identifier (String) = http://data.os.uk/id/1050MA01364874
localId (String) = 1050MA01364874
namespace (String) = http://data.os.uk/
beginLifespanVersion (String) = 2016-03-15T00:00:00.000
maintenanceResponsibility (String) = Maintainable At Public Expense
maintenanceAuthority|ResponsibleAuthority|identifier (Integer) = 1050
authorityName (String) = Derbyshire
partialReference (String) = false
highwayAuthority|ResponsibleAuthority|identifier (Integer) = 1050
highwayAuthority|ResponsibleAuthority|authorityName (String) = Derbyshire
reasonForChange (String) = New
locationDescription (String) = (null)
```

Everything else listed above has been loaded successfully into postgres.

Can anyone tell me why this is, and how I can persuade ogr2ogr to load the #usrn as well as everything else?

Comment: Can you provide the ogr command that you used to load it?

Comment: @artwork21, it was a few days ago and I didn't note down the exact command, but it would have been something straightforward, along the lines of: `ogr2ogr "PostgreSQL" PG:"host= dbname= user= password=" -t_srs EPSG:27700`

Comment: Inspire datasets can't be easily translated into the GDAL data model that is based on simple features. Your issue seems to be with xlink resolving. There is something about that in GDAL driver page http://www.gdal.org/drv_gml.html. Have you set the configuration option GML_SKIP_RESOLVE_ELEMS to NONE to enable resolution?

Comment: @user30184, I did not try GML_SKIP_RESOLVE_ELEMS to NONE. Do I simply add this into the ogr command?

Comment: Add `--config GML_SKIP_RESOLVE_ELEMS NONE`. This is documented in http://gdal.org/ogr_utilities.html.

Comment: Thanks for your help @user30184, I'll give that a try...

Comment: Ok, I'm now getting an error: `Warning 10: Couldn't find the element with id National_Maintenance_001.gml#usrn99506104`. Any ideas @user30184?

Comment: Even with sample data I would have no clue. Parsing complex GML is not simple. I would check first the contents of the GML file and try to find there really is an element with that id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer seems to be; it's not possible.

ogr2ogr does not pick up on xlinks in GML files.

My solution was to use Safe FME to load the data instead.